# calling fragment method in Activity not working kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, methods, fragment

I need to call a fragment method in the activity....

**FirstFragment.kt**

```
class FirstFragment: Fragment() {

  fun getToast(context: Context) {
    return Toast.makeText(context, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}

 }
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
  class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)



    val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, FirstFragment, FistFragmentTAG_NAME)
    transaction.commit()

     //expecting to use fragment method...
     parameter.getToast() //parameter is the code neede to call FirstFragment method .getToast()
    }


  }
```

**Ive tried these 3 cases without success**

1. Ive tried: (it crashes the app)

   ```
     FirstFragment().getToast(this@MainActivity)
   ```
2. Also tried, but the function `.getToast()` appears red

   ```
   val myToast = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FistFragmentTAG_NAME).getToast(this@MainActivity)
   ```
3. Also tried, but the funtion `.getToast()` appears red as well

   ```
      supportFragmentManager.fragments.forEach { it: Fragment

                    val getToast = it.getToast(this@MainActivity)
   ```

the problem here is not the `context`, because in the real, Im trying to call a method that doesnt use context at all... Context was set in this example just to call a `Toast`.

**How do I call the fragment method??***

Comment: Can you tell me what problem exactly you are facing?

Simply create 1 method on the fragment and from activity using fragment instance call that method.

Comment: Could you ´please provide me an example? I dont know how to instance the method in the activity...otherwise I would have tried that as well

Comment: Can you update your actual activity & fragment code? I will update that so that you will understand easily.

Comment: ok. What type of update do you expect? I posted 3 different solutions that I tried without sucess.

Comment: means how you are adding fragments from the activity. I guess you will be using fragment manager to add or replace fragments.

Comment: I did updated as expected

Comment: what is FragmentB & parameter??

Comment: those were typos. just fixed in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is activity class

```
class MyActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var myFragment: FirstFragment
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    
            myFragment = FirstFragment()
            supportFragmentManager
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment , "MyFragment")
                    .commit()
    
            //this is fragment method, we call it from activity
            myFragment.getToast(this)
        }
    
    }
```

This is fragment class

```
class FirstFragment: Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    fun getToast(context: Context) {
       Toast.makeText(context, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: what you are doing, wouldnt be the same as `FirstFragment().getToast(this@MainActivity)` ? because it crashes the app when testing as well

Comment: When exactly you want to call the getToast() method. It should be based on some action or you are directly calling it after adding a fragment.

Comment: You will get crash. Because you are trying to use context in a fragment before it got created.  Here Context is null. So it will crash due to NPE.

Comment: Yes, your code works well, it was just a mistake I made I didnt realise. thank you.